# Draw grid lines behind text reportlab pdf

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I want to create a grid like this. On top of this grid would be behind some texts or images. I have already created the text and images on the pdf, but I do not know how to create this grid behind them.

Any point in the right direction would be very helpful. A small complete solution would be more helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.units import mm


def grid_setup(mc):
    mc.setLineWidth(0.25)
    mc.setStrokeColor("red")
    mc.setStrokeAlpha(0.4)

    offset = 3 * mm
    grids = 13

    y_start = 260 * mm
    y_delta = 21 * mm
    y_left = 1 * mm
    y_right = 209 * mm

    x_start = 1 * mm
    x_delta = 20.5 * mm
    x_top = y_start
    x_bottom = y_start - (grids - 1) * y_delta - offset

    mc.line(y_left, 285 * mm, y_right, 285 * mm)
    mc.line(y_left, 275 * mm, y_right, 275 * mm)

    for x in range(grids):
        mc.line(y_left, y_start, y_right, y_start)
        mc.line(y_left, y_start - offset, y_right, y_start - offset)
        y_start -= y_delta

        mc.line(x_start, x_top, x_start, x_bottom)
        mc.line(x_start + offset, x_top, x_start + offset, x_bottom)
        x_start += x_delta


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_canvas = canvas.Canvas("page.pdf", pagesize=A4)
    grid_setup(my_canvas)
    my_canvas.drawString(10 * mm, 278 * mm, "Stackoverflow")
    my_canvas.save()
```